# Get Data From Database According Two dates

Tags: sql

SQL Query:

```
SELECT type, sum(A), sum(B) FROM TableA WHERE store_date BETWEEN '"+date1+"' AND '"+date2+"'group by type

date1="16/06/2014"

Date2="18/06/2014"
```

By this query i am getting sum of column A and column B according to the dates. I want data for column B from date1 to date2 for each type,but for column A i want data only from date1, i don't want to include date2 in sum(A)

```
**Example(Expected Result):**

  type        sum(A)   sum(B)
-------------------------------
|  fruit     |   10 |  20      |
|            |      |          |
|            |      |          |
|            |      |          |
|            |      |          |
-------------------------------
```

10 is representing sum from TableA for column A for date 16/06/2014.

20 is representing sum from TableA for column B for date 16/06/2014 to 18/06/2014.

Comment: You're going to need to split that into two SELECT statements.  There really is no other logical way to specify different criteria.

Comment: @durbnpoisn thanx for reply please specify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
Select type, sum(case when date = date1 then A else 0 end) 'A',

sum(case when date between date1 and date2 then b else 0 end) 'B'

from table 

group by type
```